# segmentation fault or bus error shown on iterms2 when running yarn

Tags: node.js, hadoop-yarn, iterm2, bus-error

[image]

whenever I run yarn start/ yarn install / or any sort of method relating yarn won't work.

however, npm does work. How do I fix this problem?

I've tried to downgrade the node.js version
but it won't work.

Comment: Did you install yarn?

Comment: What node version are you on? (`node -v`). https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7294 suggests it might be an issue with an old node version.

Comment: i've installed yarn, also my version is up to date!

Comment: the weird thing about it is that yarn works through my terminal. However, it won't work through my items or inner terminal in my vscode..

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a permission issue. Try adding the "sudo" prefix to the command

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

I got positive result adding "sudo" right before command:

```bash
npm install --global yarn
```

Like this:

```bash
sudo npm install --global yarn
```

And yarn was successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the node version if it is older than LTS then consider updating the node.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had to start running `npx yarn` instead of just `yarn` after I upgraded to node 18 for some reason.